# How to avoid crashing Rails app after removing column from table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

### The problem

I just learned that our current practice for removing a column in an ActiveRecord migration is to hide the column from Rails before actually removing it (via an ugly hack, see below for details).

This is due to the fact that Rails caches the `SHOW FULL FIELDS` query. If we don't work around that, the (long-running) migration will remove the column and by that time, Rails will have already cached the fields. Once the migration is done and the column is gone, the app will subsequently crash because `INSERT`s will provide values for a non-existing column because of the cache.

Using things like `clear_table_cache!` within the migration are of no use because we deploy to N servers and run the migration on just one of them. This would clear the cache on one of the servers but not all.

### Our current solution (a.k.a. ugly hack)

What we're currently doing is overriding [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter#columns`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/602ec7a4a21846db74f0371eb27784f19f80e28c/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L576-L587) in an initializer and deploy that before running the migration.

After the migration is done, we remove the overriding initializer and deploy again.

At this point, I cannot believe we're the only ones who encounter this problem and have to work around it. **Are there any other solution to this problem?**

Comment: Are you doing more in your migrations than building the table structures and indexes? If you are hitting insert problems my guess is that you are also manipulating data via your migrations. In my experience that always bites you on the bum! It is bad practice.

Comment: No, we're not. All the migration does is to remove the column.

Comment: nothing like being wrong :)

Comment: This is a nasty problem, i really hope rails didn't had to ask us to ignore columns in model specifically. For me, even clearing cache was not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails 5 has [added `ignored_columns`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21720) to the `ActiveRecord::Base` class:

> Since some columns will appear or disappear at any moment, you want to make those columns invisible to AR for a while. Otherwise you could have some processes knowing about the columns and others who don't.

Here's some sample code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = %w(employee_email)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used [this approach](http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/85364) before:

> We override the `ActiveRecord::Base.columns` method on the class whose column is being removed. Then we call super to retrieve the columns and strip out the columns marked for removal. Now the class can behave as if the column does not exist. […]
>
> ```
> class << self
>   RemovedColumns = {'column_to_remove' => true}
>   def columns
>     cols = super
>     cols.reject { |col| RemovedColumns.has_key? col.name }
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: You should share the details of the approach as part of your answer, or it will be deleted for being link-only.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue in the past. My approach may vary on a case-by-case basis, but I've used more than once the trick to comment the column in the `schema.rb` and deploy before running the migration.

Here's the steps:

1. Change `schema.rb` manually and comment the line where the column you want to remove is defined.
2. Deploy the changes and restart the server.
3. Create and run the migration.
4. Deploy the changes and restart the server.

As the field was commented out, the running version of the application is already ignoring it and the column is not present in the model definition.

Therefore, the migration that removes it will not need to clear the attribute cache and the application will not crash even if the migration takes longer to be completed. Of course, the field must not be used anywhere.

This approach is quite clean as it doesn't involve monkey patching or overriding Rails.

Comment: How does that help? Is the `schema.rb` ever used for something in production?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same many times.

You can use the strong_migrations gem for this.
https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#removing-a-column

The gem will complain when you try to create a "dangerous" migration and give you advises.

Comment: Thanks for this link, it pointed me to `ActiveRecord::Base#ignored_columns`!

Answer (score 0):

same thing as margo's previous answer
just cleaner imo

```
def self.columns
  super.reject { |col| col.name == 'notes' }
end
```